# Getting error in flutter google_maps_place_picker | isFromMockProvider() in Location has been deprecated

Tags: android, flutter, dart-null-safety, google-place-picker

Not sure where I made mistake but I got an error while implementing [google_maps_place_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_place_picker): any

> error: warnings found and -Werror specified
> /Users/hasnainelahi/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-6.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:29:
> warning: [deprecation] isFromMockProvider() in Location has been
> deprecated
> position.put("is_mocked", location.isFromMockProvider());

1 error
2 warnings

[Debug/Error Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz9IL.png)

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkdRv.png)

And I also given permission in Androidmanifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Flutter 2.8.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision cf44000065 (3 weeks ago) • 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
Engine • revision 40a99c5951
Tools • Dart 2.15.0

And compileSdkVersion 31, minSdkVersion 20, targetSdkVersion 29.

Hope I have given all the necessary details. If anything needs please comment and please help to solve this issue.

**Thank you in Advance**

Answer (score 1):

Can you add following to your "gradle.properties" file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

And Make sure you set the compileSdkVersion in your "android/app/build.gradle" file to 28 like following:

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 28
}
```

Comment: I tried but not working ...

Comment: Same problem here. Did you get this problem fixed?